# openssl command doesn't work so can I use php openssl functions instead

Tags: php, openssl

I think I asked this twice already and no one even bothered to view this. please help me out and try to at least think about it before forgetting the question.
So I am following this tutorial : http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php and when I used their code and inserted all the things that were different with me I ran the code and got the error message from paypal 'Unable to decrypt certificate id'. After a little of research I found that the function in the code returned 'ERROR: Encryption failed.' I think the error was caused by the following piece of code:

```
$openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                    "-outform der -nodetach -binary < \"_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n\") | " .
                    "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

if (!$error) {
    return implode("\n",$output);
} else {
    return "ERROR: encryption failed";
}
```

Is there any possible way of converting this openssl command to a `openssl_something();` call? I would greatly appreciate any help. Here is the full code and another note: PLEASE don't make stupid comments on themes such as the questions is bad, e.t.c. :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<HTML>
<?php
//Sample PayPal Button Encryption: Copyright 2006-2010 StellarWebSolutions.com
//Not for resale  - license agreement at
//http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/eula.php
//Updated: 2010 02 01

# private key file to use
$MY_KEY_FILE = "my-prvkey.pem";

# public certificate file to use
$MY_CERT_FILE = "my-pubcert.pem";

# Paypal's public certificate
$PAYPAL_CERT_FILE = "paypal_cert_pem.txt";

# path to the openssl binary
$OPENSSL = "/usr/bin/openssl";


$form = array('cmd' => '_xclick',
        'business' => 'naclo3samuel@gmail.com',
        'cert_id' => 'PRIVACY?',
        'lc' => 'RU',
        'custom' => 'test',
        'invoice' => '',
        'currency_code' => 'USD',
        'no_shipping' => '1',
        'item_name' => 'Donation',
        'item_number' => '1',
    'amount' => '10'
    );


    $encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form);


function paypal_encrypt($hash)
{
    //Sample PayPal Button Encryption: Copyright 2006-2010 StellarWebSolutions.com
    //Not for resale - license agreement at
    //http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/eula.php
    global $MY_KEY_FILE;
    global $MY_CERT_FILE;
    global $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE;
    global $OPENSSL;


    if (!file_exists($MY_KEY_FILE)) {
        echo "ERROR: MY_KEY_FILE $MY_KEY_FILE not found\n";
    }
    if (!file_exists($MY_CERT_FILE)) {
        echo "ERROR: MY_CERT_FILE $MY_CERT_FILE not found\n";
    }
    if (!file_exists($PAYPAL_CERT_FILE)) {
        echo "ERROR: PAYPAL_CERT_FILE $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE not found\n";
    }


    //Assign Build Notation for PayPal Support
    $hash['bn']= 'StellarWebSolutions.PHP_EWP2';

    $data = "";
    foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != "") {
            //echo "Adding to blob: $key=$value\n";
            $data .= "$key=$value\n";
        }
    }

    $openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                        "-outform der -nodetach -binary < \"_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n\") | " .
                        "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

    exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

    if (!$error) {
        return implode("\n",$output);
    } else {
        return "ERROR: encryption failed";
    }
};
?> 
<HEAD>
<LINK REL=stylesheet HREF="/styles/stellar.css" TYPE="text/css">
<TITLE>PHP Sample Donation using PayPal Encrypted Buttons</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor=white>
<TABLE border=0>
<TR><TD align=center>
<h1>Sample Donation Page</h1>
<P>This page uses encrypted PayPal buttons for your security.</P>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target=_blank>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="
<?PHP echo $encrypted; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Donate $10">
</form>
<P><SMALL>(PayPal will open in a new window for demonstration purposes.)</SMALL></P>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: IMHO you are not helping yourself with the "don't make stupid comments" stuff. But: What kind of server do you have? Maybe openssl is just at a different path? If you want to use `openssl_*`, afaik it must be installed at the server as well.

Comment: It is installed. And the localhost even has the https:// extension.

Comment: Then try debugging (must easier than blindly changing perfectly working code without a clue): 1) what is the exact [exit code](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html)? 2) Was there any output from the process? 3) can you run the command manually?

Comment: I ran it manually and it had no errors so I most certainly believe it is a problem with the exec(); but just a question: can I move the openssl command from /usr/bin/openssl to /var/www/html/? do I need any other commands?

Comment: You should add such information to the question. And don't move the command; that doesn't help. Maybe [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is enabled on your server?

Comment: I don't know but I suspect I do have some problems with safe_mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then here is my answer ;) You might have a problem with `safe_mode` which prevents your code from executing the openssl binary.

Comment: thank you very much. What should I do? How can I change this? do I need to change something in php.ini

Comment: That depends on your server. If you have full control, you can change it yourself in the php.ini. Otherwise talk to your admin.

Comment: I have full control. So what var do I have to change? I can't seem to find anything related.